# How to install Asus USB-N14 Adapter?

Tags: wireless, drivers, usb, adapter

I'm very new to ubuntu and can't install Asus wireless adapter driver after I tried to apply few solutions like here: https://forum.ubuntu-tr.net/index.php?topic=43087.0

Here is the driver for Asus USB-N14 Wireless-N300:

http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/wireless/USB-N14/DR_USB_N14_261320140102_Linux.zip

### Thanks for help

Edit:

```
artes@ArTeS:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0b05:17e8 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0c45:63ea Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 413c:8156 Dell Computer Corp. Wireless 370 Bluetooth Mini-card
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 413c:8158 Dell Computer Corp. Integrated Touchpad / Trackstick
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 413c:8157 Dell Computer Corp. Integrated Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
artes@ArTeS:~$ 
artes@ArTeS:~$ uname -r
3.13.0-49-generic
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of: `lsusb` and also: `uname -r`.

Comment: I edited my question with that results.

Comment: The device is covered by the module _rt2800usb_ in kernel version 3.16.0-xx. You could upgrade to Ubuntu 14.10, you could install a 3.16 kernel on the install you now have or you could compile the driver from source code. Tell me which you prefer and I will write an answer.

Comment: The second one, compiling the driver from source code please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please download [this file](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v3.18.1/backports-3.18.1-1.tar.xz) to your desktop.  Right-click it and select 'Extract Here.' Now get a temporary working internet connection by ethernet or any other means and open a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic
cd ~/Desktop/backports-3.18.1-1
make defconfig-wifi
make
sudo make install
```

This is a fairly lengthy process, so please be patient. Reboot and tell us if your wireless is working.

There is one additional step. You have compiled the driver for your currently running kernel only. When Update Manager installs a later kernel version, also known as linux-image, after the requested reboot, you must recompile:

```
cd ~/Desktop/backports-3.18.1-1
make clean
make defconfig-wifi
make
sudo make install
```

Reboot again and your wireless will again be working. Please retain the file and these instructions for that time.

Comment: It says: "Your backported driver modules should be installed now. Reboot." I rebooted and wireless is working not wireless adapter. So what's next step?

Comment: Now Asus Wireless adapter works fine after I applied the additional step. Thanks a lot. But now I can't use my wireless driver (Broadcom Corporation BCM4322). Isn't it possible to use both of them, especially when I don't have my wireless adapter ?

Comment: Please give us the information discussed here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180 Paste it here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: here it is:   http://paste.ubuntu.com/10818474/

Comment: Worked wonderfully for me on Linux Mint 17.1