# Installing an Asus usb-n14 adapter which comes with an install dvd including files for Linux

Tags: wireless, usb, asus, dvd

I downloaded [this zip file](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/wireless/USB-N14/DR_USB_N14_261320140102_Linux.zip) as suggested in [How to install Asus USB-N14 Adapter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/608536/how-to-install-asus-usb-n14-adapte)

My adapter comes with a dvd including a file named `Asus_USB-N14_LinuxSTA_Drive.tar.bz2`, contents as shown:

[image: Contents of included file]

What can I do to use the file?
Which file should I use? How do I install? 
I do not know how to use the file from the link at the top or the files pictured on the included DVD.

I am on a Dell Inspiron 5520 which originally came with Ubuntu before it was replaced by the reseller. I uninstalled everything and installed Ubuntu 2 days ago.

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0a5c:21d7 Broadcom Corp. BCM43142 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:58bf Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0b05:17e8 ASUSTek Computer, Inc.
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command

Comment: I got [make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.] as a response

Comment: Does that mean, when I get dvds with install files that are .deb files, I extract them to a folder in home and run [cd "folder name" sudo make install]? does the disc still need to be inserted while I run the commands?

Comment: The disk is not needed. And deb files are not installed this way.

Comment: Is your device working now with rtl8192cu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the driver this way

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtl8192cu-dkms linux-firmware
```

and reboot.

And you do not need any disk ;-)

Comment: I got :[make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.]

Comment: Where did you extract the files to? Did you create `Driver` folder?

Comment: How is this not an rt2800usb device? `$ modinfo rt2800usb | grep 17E8
alias:          usb:v0B05p17E8d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*`

Comment: @chili555 look into the `rt2800usb` driver code. It is not there. I guess this code is added by some mask.

Comment: @Pilot6 There it is; I posted it. What does `modinfo rt2800usb | grep -i 17e8` tell you?

Comment: @chili555 look into the source code of `rt2800usb.c`. This tells me that it is linked to the driver, but it does not tell me why. I know it is realtek. And it works.

Comment: It's listed on line 1289 of rt2800usb.c. If you think it works with rtl8192cu, please provide a link showing it. http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2800usb.c?v=3.19